# Surface with double screen - Programs not resizing

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

When I use an external 1080p monitor with my Surface, I've a problem that only Windows and it's features correctly resize to fit inside new monitor but not programs.

In example, I've several programs that are sized correctly inside one monitor but when I drag it to second monitor, all icons and windows are double in dimensions, all oversized.

Comment: Have you verified both monitors are set to the same resolution?

Comment: Yeah, there's something wrong with your resolution and scaling settings. Please [edit] the question to include resolutions and scaling you're using. You can check them in Display settings (desktop right-click)